# Loading a 2D vector from a file

Tags: c++, io, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a project for a Sudoku solver. I am trying to read the elements in a file into the board object that i have created. The code compiles fine but when ran it gives me a segmentation fault right when the file tries to open in the main function any suggestions?

here is my code for the read function:

```
void Sudoku::readPuzzle(Scanner& inStream)
{
    char placeHolder;
    int row = 1;
    int col = 1;
    int newInt;
    while(inStream.hasNext())
    {
            placeHolder = inStream.next();
            if(placeHolder == '.')
            {
                    board.setSquare(row,col,DUMMY);
            }
            else
            {
                    newInt = placeHolder;
                    board.setSquare(row,col,newInt);
            }
            if(col > NINE)
            {
                    row++;
            }
            col++;

    }

} // void Su)doku::readPuzzle(Scanner& inStream)
```

and here is the section of the main program it is giving me the fault at:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  string timeCallOutput;
  string inStreamName;
  string outStreamName;

  Scanner inStream;
  ofstream outStream;
  Sudoku sudoku;

  Utils::CheckArgs(2, argc, argv, "infilename outfilename");
  inStreamName = static_cast<string>(argv[1]);
  outStreamName = static_cast<string>(argv[2]);

  Utils::FileOpen(outStream, outStreamName);

  timeCallOutput = Utils::timecall("beginning");
  outStream << timeCallOutput;
  outStream << TAG << "\nBeginning execution" << endl;
  outStream << "infile  '" << inStreamName << "'\n";
  outStream << "outfile '" << outStreamName << "'\n";
  outStream.flush();

  inStream.openFile(inStreamName);
  cout << "File Open Succesful.";

  sudoku.readPuzzle(inStream);
  outStream << sudoku.toString("\nAfter reading");
  outStream.flush();
  inStream.close();
```

The program is giving me the fault right after it displays the outfile name.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Strip](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your code down to a minimal example that we can copy, compile and verify, if most of the lines here aren't causing the segfault then don't show them, it just slows everyone down!

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file struct".

Comment: Need code for `Utils::CheckArgs` and `Utils::FileOpen`.  Edit your question with the code or reduce the code to a minimal example that recreates the issue.

Comment: Reducing this to a minimal complete example isn't just for our convenience, it's a vital programming skill. There's a good chance the bug will become obvious to you as you clear away the extraneous code.

Comment: When you do `row++` you probably want to do `col = 0` at the same time no?

Comment: You don’t appear to check whether opening the input file was successful.  Have you tried single-stepping through in a debugger to isolate the line that crashes?

Comment: I changed a few things around and tried running for loops to fill the 2d vector instead, it fixed the segmentation fault but now i have an infinte loop with no output in my output file, seems to me my problem is in reading the file correctly